# unable to ping Oracle port 1521 in Azure VM but other ports are working fine

Tags: oracle, networking, oracle-sqldeveloper, azure-virtual-machine

I have created a VM(RHEL -linux) in Azure and installed Oracle DB on it. I want to connect to Oracle DB using 'Oracle SQL Developer' in my Windows system. The below are the Listener and tnsnames details.

```
cat listener.ora
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
           (GLOBAL_DBNAME = ORCLCDB)
           (ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1)
           (SID_NAME = ORCLCDB)
        )
)
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = azurerhel.internal.cloudapp.net)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /opt/oracle
```

The entries of `tnsnames.ora`
cat tnsnames.ora

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORCLCDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = azurerhel.internal.cloudapp.net)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCLCDB)
    )
  )

LISTENER_ORCLCDB =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = azurerhel.internal.cloudapp.net)(PORT = 1521))
```

Oracle service is working fine without any issues. and `lsnrctl status` is showing the  url for
that's different from those showing in above file.

```
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                10-DEC-2022 06:23:21
Uptime                    6 days 7 hr. 14 min. 55 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/azureRHEL/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=azureRHEL.tolzstizeobujjzahdvcdkfbwa.rx.internal.cloudapp.net)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=azureRHEL.tolzstizeobujjzahdvcdkfbwa.rx.internal.cloudapp.net)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/opt/oracle/admin/ORCLCDB/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "ORCLCDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "ORCLCDBXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "ef748d50f3d7d6efe0530400000a867c" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclpdb1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

But when i am pinging from my windows PC, all the other ports(80,22,443) are connecting fine but not port 1521.

[image]

I have already set up inbound rules for windows firewall in my PC and VM side port 1521 is opened at Azure VM as well.

[image]

[image]

I have gone through lot of search but nothing could resolve the issue and and i am unable to connect my SQL Developer. Could somebody who is expert in this networking issues shed light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the priority of 1521 port to lower. From our side, we changed the priority of the port to lower number, and it made the port working fine from my azure windows VM side. Ports with lower priority have more effect.

**Before changing the priority:**
[image]
[image]

**After changing the priority:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thankyou Sourav! Actually There was a firewall at VM side. I had to open the port 1521 manually. Then it started working for me. Thanks for your time and help.